# Why when i use interpolate hair curves modifier the original guide curve float away from the mesh

Tags: modifiers, hair, curve-modifier

I'm new in hair system. I've using blender 3.6 to create my avatar. The hair curve always fly away when I add the interpolate hair curves or Duplicate hair curves (maybe there are others but I don't test all of them)

Anyone have the same problem?

[image]